# What does the gpr_ prefix in grpc source code stand for?

Tags: naming, grpc

There are two types of prefixes in the [grpc](http://www.grpc.io/) source code： `grpc` and `gpr_`, it seems that the `gpr_` prefix is used for internal functions, but what exactly does it stand?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

"gRPC Portable Runtime." There's really nowhere that spells that out. There's only [one comment](https://github.com/grpc/grpc/pull/2268#discussion_r33708783) in one PR that mentions it.

If you've ever heard of APR (Apache Portable Runtime), then it might not be too surprising.